# Batch write operations on Firebase using dart for flutter, for a public donation app from suppliers to specific projects

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Hi I've been using FlutterFlow which is Flutter and Firebase as a backend.

My APP is a charity public donation app, to let people donate products from supplier to specific projects.

It's all done but I got stuck with the batch writes, I've only got one running code sample that I'd like to evolve to do the following Operations:

- Moving cart items where userref is passed to donation subcollection also donationref is passed (order items).
- Find and Update the projects total donated amount and quantities targets from the donation items subtotals and quantities.
- Create and update delivery records to the suppliers referenced in donation items subcollections and update the Qty for the pending orders from donation items.
- Create and update daily/weekly/monthly records in reports collections for the donations based on projects/suppliers/products from total amounts and quanities.

This is the code that I think it's best to evolve

```
Future batchUpdateListValue(String? updateCollection, String? updateField,
    bool? currentValue, bool? newValue, DocumentReference donationref) async {


  CollectionReference collectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(updateCollection!);



  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();


  collectionRef.where(updateField!, isEqualTo: currentValue).get()

      .then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {

      batch.update(
          document.reference, {updateField: newValue, 'donation': donationref});
    });

    return batch.commit();
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `batch.commit()` outside the `.then()` ?

Comment: actually my current problem is getting the donation document from the donation document reference and adding that to the subcollection of items as in a batch.set